Postman Mailgun events unauthorized
I am trying to connect to Mailgun's event api using postman. I am providing my login credentials with the request however I keep getting unauthorized error. Can someone help me point out what's wrong. Below is the screenshot of my request.

I have also tried a curl request like curl -i -X GET -u karan.sharma@muhc.mcgill.ca:***** 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/ena.muhc.mcgill.ca/events' but I am getting the same error

Found the solution: the username in this case is api and the password is your API_SECRET
